# why is my web routes going to api routes? laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, api

so in my blade files i have these code to do CRUD,

```
    <form method="POST" class="form-horizontal" action="{{ url('tickets/'.$ticket->id) }}"
                  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                     {!! csrf_field() !!}
                     <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH" />
```

so i created my api routes. code below. (routes/api.php)

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['api']], function () {
    Route::resource('/v1/tickets','Api\TicketsController');
});
```

these are my routes. for web, it's in routes.php, because i got it from a package.

```
Route::resource($main_route_path, 'App\Http\Controllers\TicketsController', [
            'names' => [
                'index'   => $main_route.'.index',
                'store'   => $main_route.'.store',
                'create'  => $main_route.'.create',
                'update'  => $main_route.'.update',
                'show'    => $main_route.'.show',
                'destroy' => $main_route.'.destroy',
                'edit'    => $main_route.'.edit',
            ],
            'parameters' => [
                $field_name => 'ticket',
            ],
        ]);
```

now, the PROBLEM, is that every time i click the button using the form request, the whole operation goes to the api, any thoughts why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

All the routes in the api.php are grouped with the prefix, middleware and namespace by default. You don't have to add the `api` middleware again like you are.

For the web routes you can just use **TicketsController** since the namespace already points to the Controllers folder.

Can you run `php artisan route:list` and see what shows up?

Also you can do this to change the name prefix of all resource routes.

```
Route::resource($main_route_path, 'TicketsController', [
    'names' => $main_route,
    'parameters' => [
        $field_name => 'ticket',
    ],
]);
```